# Assign names to variable using regular expression in R

Tags: regex, r

So I have a bunch of variables in my workspace. I want to assign a subset of them to a new variable, so I can easily run functions on this subset:

workspace:

```
...
group10
group40
location40
test
```

desired assignment:

```
groupList <- list(group10,group40, ...)
```

intended regular expression:

```
^group[0-9]+
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to assign the _names_ "group10" and "group40" to a new variable, or the _values_ associated with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` accepts a `pattern` argument:

```
group10 <- group40 <- location40 <- test <- NA
mysub <- ls(pattern="^group[0-9]+")
mysub
#[1] "group10" "group40"
```

You can use `lapply` to loop over the list of variable names and `get` their values

```
groupList <- lapply(mysub, get)
```

or, in one line

```
groupList <- lapply(ls(pattern="^group[0-9]+"), get)
```

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of get. Thanks, mate!