# Run function in data frames within list

Tags: r, object

So I have a bunch of data frames in a list object. Frames are organised such as

```
ID     Category    Value
2323   Friend      23.40
3434   Foe         -4.00
```

And I got them into a list by following [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168944/assign-names-to-variable-using-regular-expression-in-r).

Now how do I recursively run a function in each data frame? For example, how would I use tolower(colnames(x)) to change column names within data frames to lowercase?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have a `list` of `data.frame`s and you want to apply the same action to all `data.frame`s in the `list`?

Comment: Yes @mrdwab. Sorry for the confusion, I'm editing the post to correct that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample `data.frame` and a `list` with that `data.frame` repeated twice.

```
test <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="ID     Category    Value
 2323   Friend      23.40
 3434   Foe         -4.00")
temp <- list(A = test, B = test)
```

If you just wanted to change the names of the original `data.frame`, try:

```
names(test) <- tolower(names(test))
test
#     id category value
# 1 2323   Friend  23.4
# 2 3434      Foe  -4.0
```

If you wanted to change the names of all the `data.frame`s in the `list`, try:

```
lapply(temp, function(x) { names(x) = tolower(names(x)); x })
# $A
#     id category value
# 1 2323   Friend  23.4
# 2 3434      Foe  -4.0
# 
# $B
#     id category value
# 1 2323   Friend  23.4
# 2 3434      Foe  -4.0
```