# Conditional lapply

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, lapply

So I have a bunch of data frames in a list object. Frames are organised such as

```
ID     Category    Value
2323   Friend      23.40
3434   Foe         -4.00
```

And I got them into a list by following [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168944/assign-names-to-variable-using-regular-expression-in-r). I can also run simple functions on them as shown in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172456/run-function-in-data-frames-within-list).

Now I am trying to run a **conditional** function with lapply, and I'm running into trouble. In some tables the 'ID' column has a different name (say, 'recnum'), and I need to tell lapply to go through each data frame, check if there is a column named 'recnum', and change its name to 'ID', as in

```
colnr <- which(names(x) == "recnum"
if (length(colnr > 0)) {names(x)[colnr] <- "ID"}
```

But I'm running into trouble with local scope and who knows what. Any ideas?

Comment: Minimal reproducible example please - your title and text talk about lapply, but your code example doesn't. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5965451/334485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the second part of mnel's answer, you can see that the function `foo` evaluates `x` as its last expression. Without that, if you try to change the names of the data.frames in your list directly from within the anonymous function passed to `lapply`, it will likely not work.

Just as an alternative, you could use `gsub` and avoid loading an additional package (although `plyr` is a nice package):

```
xx <- list(data.frame("recnum" = 1:3, "recnum2" = 1:3),
  data.frame("ID" = 4:6, "hat" = 4:6))

lapply(xx, function(x){ 
  names(x) <- gsub("^recnum$", "ID", names(x))
  return(x)
})
# [[1]]
#   ID recnum2
# 1  1       1
# 2  2       2
# 3  3       3

# [[2]]
#   ID hat
# 1  4   4
# 2  5   5
# 3  6   6
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `rename` function from `plyr`; it renames by name, not position:

```
x <- data.frame(ID = 1:2,z=1:2)
y <- data.frame('recnum' = 1:2,z=3:4)

.list <- list(x,y)
library(plyr)
lapply(.list, rename, replace = c('recnum' = 'ID'))

[[1]]
  ID z
1  1 1
2  2 2

[[2]]
  ID z
1  1 3
2  2 4
```

Your original code works fine:

```
foo <- function(x){
  colnr <- which(names(x) == "recnum")

  if (length(colnr > 0)) {names(x)[colnr] <- "ID"}
  x
}
.list <- list(x,y)
lapply(.list, foo)
```

Not sure what your problem was.